# Windows program to report keypresses

Tags: windows, debugging, keyboard, virtualization, keypress

**Problem:** I am using Windows as a guest operating system in a Virtual Machine and a funky keyboard setup. I need a way to be able to troubleshoot cases when keyboard hotkey combinations are not functioning properly.

**Question:** Does anyone know of a program that quickly and easily displays on the screen what keypress windows thinks it got whenever I press a key or key combination on the installed keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Keyboard Jedi**](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2007/06/03/train-to-be-a-keyboard-master-with-keyboard-jedi.aspx) looks like it will do what you're after.